# Fancybox not displaying iframe content

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, fancybox

I'm trying to display a html form (not inline) in a fancybox. However, clicking the link just re-directs to the actual page containing the form. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Below is an excerpt of my code:

Html:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/mysite/popups/registration_1.html" class="register">register</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.register").fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe'
    });
});
```

I can't figure out for the life of me what I'm doing wrong. Looking at the fancybox documentation, the above appears to be correct syntactically.

I'm using the latest fancybox release (as of writing this), version: 1.3.4.

Any thoughts, or ideas would be much appreciated...

Thanks,

-Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if you are including the jQuery JS file before the Fancybox JS file and that their paths to the file you are including are right.

I've maded a test in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLcMh/) and it worked. Note that I've included the JS and CSS for the fancybox at the left and selected jQuery.

Comment: Okay, so changing the path precedence has made some impact. However, instead of re-directing, nothing happens; no lightbox overlay, nada...

Comment: Interestingly, when I remove the forced type; 'iframe', the form is appended to the bottom of the current page.

Comment: Okay, after cross-checking the sample code in the fancybox distro, noticed that I didn't include the 'rel="stylesheet"' attribute/value in the link element for the fancybox css. The form is now being displayed. Many thanks for your help

Comment: No prob. Glad to see you've figured it out.